# If you merge a branch into master, are differences overwritten by the branch that is merged?

Tags: git

Lets say I make a branch "branch1" from master. I make a bunch of changes on branch1, and a few changes on master. If I merge branch1 into master, will all the changes to master be removed and will the code be overwritten by branch1? Or will they mesh together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They will mesh together. There may be conflicts you have to manually resolve. You can set merge strategies to resolve conflicts by default.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a workflow where you rebase branch1 against master before merging.

Check out http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
and the git flow tool https://github.com/nvie/gitflow